# Using Sympy Equations for Plotting

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, symbols, sympy

What is the best way to create a Sympy equation, do something like take the derivative, and then plot the results of that equation?

I have my symbolic equation, but can't figure out how to make an array of values for plotting. Here's my code:

```
from sympy import symbols
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

t = symbols('t')
x = 0.05*t + 0.2/((t - 5)**2 + 2)

nums = []
for i in range(1000):
    nums.append(t)
    t += 0.02

plotted = [x for t in nums]

mpl.plot(plotted)
mpl.ylabel("Speed")
mpl.show()
```

In my case I just calculated the derivative of that equation, and now I want to plot the speed `x`, so this is fairly simplified.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.linspace()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace) to create the values of the x axis (`x_vals` in the code below) and [`lambdify()`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#module-sympy.utilities.lambdify).

```
from sympy import symbols
from numpy import linspace
from sympy import lambdify
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

t = symbols('t')
x = 0.05*t + 0.2/((t - 5)**2 + 2)
lam_x = lambdify(t, x, modules=['numpy'])

x_vals = linspace(0, 10, 100)
y_vals = lam_x(x_vals)

mpl.plot(x_vals, y_vals)
mpl.ylabel("Speed")
mpl.show()
```

<sub>(improvements  suggested by [asmeurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161801/asmeurer) and [MaxNoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3838691/maxnoe))</sub>

[image]

Alternatively, you can use sympy's `plot()`:

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy import plot

t = symbols('t')
x = 0.05*t + 0.2/((t - 5)**2 + 2)

plot(x, (t, 0, 10), ylabel='Speed')
```

Comment: It's better to use `lambdify` to create a numpy friendly expression from the sympy expression than to use subs.

Comment: It will be even faster if you do `lambdify(t, x, modules=['numpy'])` and `y_vals = lam_x(x_vals)`

Comment: @asmeurer Indeed, `lambdify()` instead of my inefficient list comprehension with `subs()`, makes it 4 times faster.

Comment: @MaxNoe My tests show about 1-10% increase in speed which feels rather small. I ll include it though, since I guess it might have a more significant effect in other cases.

Comment: For simple functions and few points the increase might be small,  but not for more complex stuff and more points.

Answer (score 9):

## Using SymPy

You can use directly the [plotting functions of SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html):

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot as symplot

t = symbols('t')
x = 0.05*t + 0.2/((t - 5)**2 + 2)
symplot(x)
```

[image]

Most of the time it uses matplotlib as a backend.

Comment: how to extend this to a function of two variables? f(x,y) instead of f(x)?

Comment: @baxx that's another question you should ask in another thread, however  you can use plot implicit https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html