# Creating a plot of a SymPy expression with a a equation with multiple variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sympy

I have figured out how to make a equation with SymPy, however, I am not sure how to plot the relationship between two values. I keep getting an `TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float` whenever I write `plt.plot(Rho , T)`. I have a code like this so far:

```
import matplotlib as plt
from sympy import init_session

init_session()

rho, X, Y, Z, T_9, T, T_8, m, n, Gamma = symbols('rho X Y Z T_9 T T_8 m n Gamma')

q_pp = (2.4 * 10**(4) * rho * X**2 / T_9**(2/3)) * exp((-3.380/T_9**(1/3)))
q_CNO = (4.4 * 10**(25) * rho * X* Z/ T_9**(2/3)) * exp((-15.228/T_9**(1/3)))

q_min = q_pp + q_CNO
simplify(q_min)

T_9 = T / (10**9)

Rho = (10**3)*(T_9**(1/3) / (24000 * X * exp(15.228/T_9**(1/3)) + (4.4*10**25) * Z * exp(3.38/T_9**(1/3)))) * exp(-18.608/ T_9**(1/3))
simplify(Rho)

plot_implicit(T, Rho)
```

Updated: I used SymPy plot to get new error, I updated the code to reflect what I currently have, `TypeError: object of type 'Mul' has no len()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Matplotlib doesn't understand about sympy expressions. You'll need sympy's plot.

Comment: Okay, so I tried sympy plot, and I got a new error, this one is `TypeError: object of type 'Mul' has no len()` . So, would I have to use specify a range with `numpy.linspace(, , )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide values for the independent variable(s). For example, to plot an expression like `y = x**2 - 1`, I would do this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 20)  # Provide the range of the independent variable.
y = x**2 - 1          # Compute the dependent variable.

plt.plot(x, y)
```

In your case, you'll need to provide values for `T` I suppose, and it looks like there are several other unknowns too. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390187/using-sympy-equations-for-plotting), answers to which show a SymPy plotting example.